# How to use setFlash() method in a view (cakePHP)?

Tags: cakephp, view

I think the question is clear enough. I tried doing this:

I created `message.ctp` in `view/elements`, this is its content:

```
<div class="flash message">
    <?php echo $message ?>
</div>
```

And I tried generating this message in a view:

```
echo $this->Session->flash(
    'Aucune absence pour le mois selectionné !',
    array('element' => 'message')
);
```

It doesn't display anything, not even an error message. what am I missing?

Comment: There is no view helper that allows writing to the session. You should do that in your action via component. PS: My [implementation of flash messages](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/04/21/cakephp-flash-messages-2-0/) provides this via Configure.

Comment: Any other solution please ? :D
i find yours difficult to apply for me :/

Comment: Yes: Using the controller action and writing to the session there.

Comment: Can you explain more, an exemple of code would be appreciated.

Comment: It's documented: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html#displaying-notifications-or-flash-messages

Answer (score 0):

Set this code in controller:

```
  $this->Session->setFlash( 'Your Message' , null, null, 'element_name');
```

Use this code on message.ctp file

```
<div class="flash message">
   <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
</div>
```